# Azure PostgreSQL flexi sever local pgAdmin connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, azure-postgresql

I'm currently integrating our database with the Azure PostgreSQL Flexi server in the cloud. I've successfully set up the server on the Azure platform, but I'm encountering connectivity issues when attempting to establish a connection using my local pgAdmin or PowerShell.

Unfortunately, I've been consistently experiencing request timeouts. Even when trying to connect via PowerShell using the command `.\psql.exe -h app-domain-name-non-prod-server.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U dummyUser`, I'm faced with the following error:

`psql: error: connection to server at "app-domain-name-non-prod-server.postgres.database.azure.com" (1.0.0.5), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

*I also tried to ping the domain and I am getting 100% loss in the ping results*

I have added a lot of IP addresses which I get from my PC when I type 'ipconfig` in the Firewall settings under Networking of my Postgres server but still, I am encountering connectivity issues see below snapshot

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4BPs.png).

I have limited knowledge about firewall configurations, but as far as I understand, I need to include my PC's IP address. The challenge arises when I see numerous IP addresses listed after typing `ipconfig`, causing confusion about which one to select. Additionally, since I'm working on my company's PC, I'm uncertain whether I need to adjust my PC settings to permit outbound connections. If that's the case, could you provide guidance on where I can make these adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

Add the client IP address to the firewall rule as shown below:

[image]

Afterward, try connecting to the PostgreSQL server from pgAdmin by providing the required details and clicking on save while registering the server, as shown below:

[image]

This will successfully connect to pgAdmin, as shown below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues).